# Branch for testing

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, source-control-explorer

When using `Team Foundation Server`, is there a generally accepted way to approach branching when you need to test certain approaches to issues that come up (bugs, feature requests, etc)?

Say, for example, that you are on a team with a few other developers and one developer says that he just cannot figure out how to solve this problem and asks you for assistance. You have some ideas but you want to make sure that you don't accidentally make changes to his main branch of code in case your ideas don't work.

At this point you could either:

- Make a local copy and unbind it from source control to ensure you do not accidentally check in any changes in the future.
- Create a branch from his branch and call it "Testing" or something, and delete the branch once you are done with it.
- Check out a copy of his branch and simply "undo pending changes" when you decide your approaches don't work (this seems dangerous).

I know you could probably approach it a few other ways but I was just curious as to whether or not there was a popular way to approach making "test changes" to code thats under source control.

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC?

Answer (score 2):

Branching is best kept for multiple simultaneous, independent changes.

Use a Shelveset for the purposes you're discussing. That's how the "Suspend" feature of "My Work" works, and it's how code reviews work. They shelve the changes, attach them to the Code Review work item, and inform the reviewers. The reviewers can unshelve the changes, look at them and make comments, and possibly even edit them. They can then shelve their version of the changes and send them back to you.

There's a lot of flexibility there, without creating branches, which are permanent artifacts.

Update: You can additionally execute a build and set the Shelveset name in the version to build property to create a custom build from your shelveset.